# Can't deploy Laravel php app to azure via GitHub

Tags: php, laravel, azure, github

When trying to connect a private GitHub repo containing a Laravel app to an azure "Web app + postgres" on the php stack I am getting this error:

"The app 'example' is setup with stack 'php' which is currently not supported in Deployment Center via GitHub Actions."

However various guides im following seem to not have this problem.
such as this one [Deploy Laravel on Azure Web App](https://medium.com/swlh/deploy-laravel-5-8-on-azure-web-app-2019-3514eb2fd1af)

Anyone have any pointers as to what could be going on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple fix: select "App Service Build Service" as the Build provider. It's hidden in the UI so you need to dig around for it as GitHub Actions is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem before, so I don't recommend you to use github for continuous deployment of php projects for the time being.

**Solutions and reference documents:**

1. I recommend using localgit to publish your project.

   [Official document] [Push to Azure from Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-linux#push-to-azure-from-git)
2. [Hosting a Laravel Application on Azure Web App](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46)